# I am trying to find how many vowels and consonants in my string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main()
 {
   int i;
   int counter=0, counter2=0;
   char *s;
   char name[30];
   char vowel[6] = "AEIOU";
   char consonants[21] = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";

   printf ("input the string: ");
   scanf  ("%s", name);
   printf ("The string is %s\n", name);
   for (i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++) {
     if (s = strchr(vowel, name[i])) {
       counter++;
     }
     else if (s =strchr(consonants, name[i])) {
       counter2++;
     }
     printf ("First counter is %d\n", counter);
     printf ("The second counter is %d\n", counter2);
     return 0;
   }
 }
```

And the question is, what is wrong with my code? why counter is not working?
Because I tried a lot of ways, and nothing works, maybe someone can explain for me.

Comment: You might add how exactly your program fails - does it print anything? What does it print?

Comment: How is this different to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864558/stack-with-finding-character-inside-string-in-c-language

Comment: And please, in the future, indent your code. It helps you, and it helps people who are reading your code (which includes your teacher).

Comment: Consider using more descriptive names for your counters than `counter` and `counter2`.  How about `vowel_count` and `consonant_count`?

Answer (score 10):

I've added indentation to your code, and by doing this, it becomes quite obvious that your issue is that your return and print statements are inside the for loop. They should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the `}` and `{` placement issue, `consonants[21]` should be `consonants[22]`. A safer way would be to use `consonants[]` - the compiler would count the number of characters for you.

Answer (score 2):

The three last lines are:

```
    return 0;
  }
}
```

but should be:

```
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Lesson: indentation is important.

Answer (score 2):

First, there are 21 consonants in the english alphabet, so your array should be 22 elements long (to accommodate the terminating '\0' char).

Second, you don't need to test for consonants at all, since if it's not a vowel it is a consonant. So you can clean this up by removing the consonants array completely, and simply using an else statement rather than redundantly checking your array for consonants.

Third, did you intend to print the value of each counter for each letter in name? That seems odd.
Also, you should only return once. Currently you're only going through the loop once, and then returning from main. That's not right... You should move both of the printf's and the return statement outside of your for loop. Thats all I got... Your code should run find if you make those fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `scanf` to read strings of an arbitrary length:

```
#XXX never do that
char name[30];
scanf("%s", name);
```

If input is larger than the specified size then [bad things](http://ideone.com/hp6Mo) can happen such as arbitrary code being executed.

You could use `fgets` instead:

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
  // buf contains a line or part of it;
  // long lines are spread among multiple chunks
  process_chunk(buf);
}

if (!feof(stdin))
  ; // error
```

<sub>It should be a comment; I've posted it as an answer to include the code example.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Nice use of `strchr`!  One of my favorite functions in `string.h`.  A few notes though:

1. You're only checking for uppercase characters.  Take a look at `toupper()` to convert the test character to uppercase before comparing it to your vowel list.
2. If a character is a letter, and it's not a vowel, then it's a consonant.  Instead of building up a separate array for consonants, take a look at the `isalpha()` function and think about how you could incorporate it into your program instead of a second call to `strchr()`.  Now you don't have to worry about forgetting a character in the consonant list!